# Multi Module Maven Project

Tags: maven

I want to develop a multi module maven project structure which contain five individual modules, one of which is web-based.

I need to know the Structure of the project, which could be the best and easy to implement.

Also how i can maintain the pom, in different folder structure.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem? Parent pom.xml in root folder, modules in separate folders under the root one.

Comment: if i have 5 folders of seperate java files(modules), where i have to put all their pom(child pom.xml)?

Comment: pom.xml for each module should be placed in in module directory. See [`here`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects) for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
+-- root 
|    +--- pom.xml //parent pom with <modules>
+-- module-a
|     +--- pom.xml
+-- module-b
|     +--- pom.xml
+-- module-c
|     +--- pom.xml
+-- module-d
|     +--- pom.xml
+-- module-web
      +--- pom.xml //web module with <packaging>war</packaging>
```